# Converting nested for loop into a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I currently am trying to make a very primitive object detection system by taking an image as input, converting it to a list using PIL image, and sorting out pixels that are close enough to a predetermined color. I then take the average of those to get the location.

I'm planning to use this with a distance sensor and some basic trig to make a root that can grab objects without having to hard code it.

I've coded it using for loops, but it currently takes several seconds to run, and I wanted to put it into list comprehension, but I have no idea how to use list comprehension with nested loops and if statements.
I've tried looking at tutorials online, but everything I've seen has been for simple list comprehension with only 1 variable or loop, and am completely lost

Here is the code I'm using

```
for x in range(0, len(image)):
  for y in range(0, len(image[x])):
    pixel = image[x][y]
    #had to split because line was too long: line too long (180 > 88 characters)
    if (pixel[0] > red - error and pixel [0] < red + error):
      if (pixel[1] > green - error and pixel [1] < green + error):
        if (pixel[2] > blue - error and pixel [2] < blue + error):
          goodPixels.append([x,y])
```

and here is the [link to my replit project](https://replit.com/@JonathanMabardy/Object-Detection?v=1)

Comment: I would strongly suggest not using for loops or list comprehensions for this task. Instead, you can convert the image to a numpy array and remove pixels that match your criteria.

Comment: Converting a nested loop to a list comprehension won't make it run any faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over the pixel values, I suggest converting the image to a numpy array and working with that. If you are not familiar with NumPy, it is the de facto standard way of working with numerical data in Python, and it lets us avoid the trouble of looping over individual rows / columns.

I include an example below of how you can get the pixel values that fit your criteria.

The values are all arbitrary, so you will have to put in your image and values for rgb thresholds.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

pil_im = Image.new("RGB", (128, 128))
image = np.array(pil_im)

red = 128
green = 50
blue = 200
error = 5

red_min = red - error
red_max = red + error
green_min = green - error
green_max = green + error
blue_min = blue - error
blue_max = blue + error

pixel_is_red = np.logical_and(image[:, :, 0] > red_min, image[:, :, 0] < red_max)
pixel_is_green = np.logical_and(image[:, :, 1] > green_min, image[:, :, 1] < green_max)
pixel_is_blue = np.logical_and(image[:, :, 2] > blue_min, image[:, :, 2] < blue_max)

# Get a boolean matrix of the pixels that are R, G, and B.
final_mask = pixel_is_red & pixel_is_green & pixel_is_blue

# Index the original image with our boolean mask, to recover the good pixels.
good_pixels = image[final_mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mkrieger1 has pointed out in the comments, list comprehension doesn't necessarily improve performance over building a list with nested loops. It's mainly used for code conciseness and better readability for the programmers. Although it's possible to write very complex list comprehensions with several `for` clauses and expressions, they're often discouraged, as it's the case in [Google's style guide for Python](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#274-decision) for example.

Still, for the sake of understanding list comprehension, the code you provided would look something like this:

```
goodPixels = [[x, y] for x in range(len(image)) for y in range(len(image[x])) if (image[x][y][0] > red - error and image[x][y][0] < red + error) and (image[x][y][1] > green - error and image[x][y][1] < green + error) and (image[x][y][2] > blue - error and image[x][y][2] < blue + error)]
```

As complex list comprehensions can be way too long, you would probably want to indent them:

```
goodPixels = [
  [x, y]
  for x in range(len(image)) 
  for y in range(len(image[x])) 
  if (image[x][y][0] > red - error and image[x][y][0] < red + error)
      and (image[x][y][1] > green - error and image[x][y][1] < green + error)
      and (image[x][y][2] > blue - error and image[x][y][2] < blue + error)
]
```